# Localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE results when I am running server on port 3000 even if I set google credentials

Tags: node.js, mongoose, google-api, passport.js

This is the code I have been using to make a request to Google Server. Please look through this.

```
  //jshint esversion:6
   require("dotenv").config();

  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const express = require("express");
  const ejs = require("ejs");
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");
  const session  = require("express-session");
  const passport = require("passport");
  const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
  const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
  const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate");


  const app = express();
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 app.use(express.static("public"));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

 app.use(session({
    secret:"Our Little Secret File Here.",
   resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
 }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
   clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
   clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
// userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
},
 function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  return cb(err, user);
  });
 }
));
```

Code is not working to talk to Google Server. Plase fix thi;s there is some issue please.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you say that it is not working... does it mean...? Any error? unexpected result???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //jshint esversion:6
   require("dotenv").config();

  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const express = require("express");
  const ejs = require("ejs");
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");
  const session  = require("express-session");
  const passport = require("passport");
  const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
  const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
  const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate");


  const app = express();
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 app.use(express.static("public"));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

 app.use(session({
    secret:"Our Little Secret File Here.",
   resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
 }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
   clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
   clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
// userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
},
 function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  return cb(err, user);
  });
 }
));
```

Can you try this one, I just updated the import package part.